# Drop the row of dataframe if it's duplicate and if yes drop all except with minimum time

Tags: dataframe

I have two columns "key" and "time". If the key is same then compare time, keep the minimum time row and drop other with that particular key.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "key": [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1],
  "time": [12.4,12.6,12.8,12.5,12.9,12.3,12.8,12.1],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

I tried with duplicate() but it returns series. Tried many other things but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use groupby over `key` and aggregate by minimum as in:

`df.groupby(['key']).agg('min')`

Comment: I had multiple columns so used
df.groupby(['month','key']).agg({'time' : ['min']})